# What are the differences between readonly vs get in TypeScript properties?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is there a functional difference between declaring a property in TypeScript as `readonly` vs creating it through a `get()`? Both behave the same, but it'd be good to know if there is a reason to use one over the other besides preference.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It makes a difference to the generated JavaScript: The getter will be an accessor property (e.g., function), the `readonly` property will be a data property. This:

```
class Example {
    get foo(): string {
        return "foo";
    }
    readonly bar: string = "bar";
}
```

converts to this if you target ES2015+:

```
"use strict";
class Example {
    constructor() {
        this.bar = "bar";
    }
    get foo() {
        return "foo";
    }
}
```

[Live on the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/MYGwhgzhAECiAeYC2AHEBTaBvAUNf0A5ugC7QBmA9pQBQCUAXNBCQE4CWAdodngf61IBXVp2gAiKpXEBuPvgC+86ILAATSpxABPaACMwrJiw7doAXgkHWsnAqA)

or to this if you target ES5+:

```
"use strict";
var Example = /** @class */ (function () {
    function Example() {
        this.bar = "bar";
    }
    Object.defineProperty(Example.prototype, "foo", {
        get: function () {
            return "foo";
        },
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true
    });
    return Example;
}());
```

[Live on the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?target=1#code/MYGwhgzhAECiAeYC2AHEBTaBvAUNf0A5ugC7QBmA9pQBQCUAXNBCQE4CWAdodngf61IBXVp2gAiKpXEBuPvgC+86ILAATSpxABPaACMwrJiw7doAXgkHWsnAqA)

Notice that although TypeScript considers `bar` read-only, nothing enforces that at runtime. `foo`, on the other hand, is read-only even at runtime. (Although if you *really* wanted to, you could use `Object.defineProperty` to defeat it by reconfiguring the property.)

Comment: Tried it with the option to output ES5 and it's still different. Interesting.

Comment: I did a little extra digging on my own as I wrote the question, and came across this. I was still surprised that this question wasn't on here, so I wanted to provide it for everyone. If no one answered in a couple hours, I was going to provide this as an answer. Thanks! I'll see if anyone else has anything more to say.

Answer (score 15):

A getter is evaluated again on every property access, and creates a new value. This is an important functional difference, as that behaviour is usually not what you want:

```
class Example {
    get foo(): object {
        return {};
    }
    readonly bar: object = {};
}
const example: Example = new Example;
console.log(example.foo === example.foo); // false
console.log(example.bar === example.bar); // true
```

For the implementation details, see @T.J.Crowder's excellent answer which I won't repeat here.

Comment: The way that you wrote your answer, yes a new value will be created each time. However, there are other ways to get around that, if it is important to maintain the same value whether due to expensive calls or maintaining references.

Comment: But in most cases, this is a very important distinction.

Comment: This is a great answer!